# Active admin integration in Java EE project

Tags: jakarta-ee, maven, jruby, activeadmin

I have an active admin project which manage my database tables, and I want to integrate it in to an existing Java EE project (Maven, Spring 3, Struts 2).

I heard that's possible with Jruby. So, where to start? Is there any tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends what do you mean by "integrate"..

If it is just running your active admin in the same Java EE container, you basically need to do  the following:

1. Install & setup  ActiveRecord JDBC Adapter (https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter#activerecord-jdbc-adapter)
2. Install warbler. (https://github.com/jruby/warbler#warbler-)
3. Create `.war` deployment by running `warble`
4. Deploy the `.war` into your Java EE container.

You can find JRuby docs here: https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki